# What does returning by constant reference do? [C++]

Tags: c++, function, reference, constants

Can someone explain what is the point of returning by constant reference? I know that when you just return a reference, you are returning an alias to that object you are returning. However, I am not sure what adding the word 'const' changes what it does. Thanks!

Comment: `const` means it can't be changed.

Comment: `const` forces the program to let the reference constant. It also may be a hint for compiler to do some optimizations

Comment: to have a read only ref. for example

Comment: @Goddrew Ask yourself what the qualifier const means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ Return value, reference, const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778045/c-return-value-reference-const-reference)

Answer (score 2):

A good example would be `std::vector::operator[]`.  There are two overloads of that function, a const version that returns a `const` reference and a non-const version that returns a regular reference.  If you use the `const` version you cannot assign a new value.

```
void func(const std::vector<int> & const_vec, std::vector<int> & vec)
{
    const_vec[0] = 906;  // will fail with compiler error
    vec[0] = 906;  // works fine if vec.size() >= 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most times the point in returning a "const ref" (a reference to a constant object) is to give the calling code read only access to the property of a `class`.

`T const &` (or `const T &`) denotes a reference to an object that can't be altered using the reference. Hence only `const`-qualified member functions can be called.

Comment: *Can't be modified without using a cast

Comment: But don't use a cast unless you know ***exactly*** what you are doing. And probably not even then.

Comment: @Ayxan I contemplated mentioning `const_cast<>` but ...